# Cannot Detect CPU Temperature?

Tags: 64-bit, centos-7, sensors, lm-sensors

```
# sensors-detect
# sensors-detect revision 3.4.0-8 (2016-06-01)
# System: Supermicro Super Server [0123456789]
# Board: Supermicro H11DSi
# Kernel: 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64
# Processor: AMD EPYC 7742 64-Core Processor (23/49/0)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           Success!
    (driver `k10temp')
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): yes
Found `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca2...                            Success!
    (confidence 8, driver `to-be-written')

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Found unknown SMBus adapter 1022:790b at 0000:00:14.0.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Next adapter: AST i2c bit bus (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: igb BB (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES

Next adapter: igb BB (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at 0b00 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 2 at 0b00 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 3 at 0b00 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 4 at 0b00 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue:   

Driver `to-be-written':
  * ISA bus, address 0xca2
    Chip `IPMI BMC KCS' (confidence: 8)

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 17h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

Note: there is no driver for IPMI BMC KCS yet.
Check https://hwmon.wiki.kernel.org/device_support_status for updates.

No modules to load, skipping modules configuration.

Unloading i2c-dev... OK

[root@localhost ~]# sensors
i350bb-pci-6100
Adapter: PCI adapter
loc1:         +38.0°C  (high = +120.0°C, crit = +110.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +36.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00cb
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +35.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
```

Any idea why it can't detect per core temperature like this [article](https://www.osradar.com/check-your-cpu-temperature-in-linux/) shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Zen-Temps-Hwmon-Next), a newer driver/kernel is needed:

The temperature monitoring support didn't make it for Linux 4.14 but being published earlier this month were finally patches for Zen temperature monitoring by extending the k10temp Linux driver.

And a user on centos forum [confirmed](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=71383).